How to type hint numpy arrays that accept any types of numpy floats?
As per question, I want to define a numpy type that accepts any numpy floats (i.e. np.float64, np.float32 etc. Currently I am doing the below, is there a way to bound the NDArray such any subclass of np.floating is allowed?
from numpy.typing import NBitBase, NDArray
import numpy as np

any_np_float: NDArray[Any]


Check [NumPy]: Scalars ([NumPy]: Typing (numpy.typing) might also be useful).
You could search [Python.Docs]: Built-in Types - class.__mro__ for your desired types and find a common ancestor.

>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>>
>>> floats = [e for e in dir(np) if "float" in e]
>>>
>>> floats
['cfloat', 'clongfloat', 'complexfloating', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64', 'float_', 'float_power', 'floating', 'format_float_positional', 'format_float_scientific', 'longfloat']
>>>
>>> np.float32.__mro__
(<class 'numpy.float32'>, <class 'numpy.floating'>, <class 'numpy.inexact'>, <class 'numpy.number'>, <class 'numpy.generic'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> np.float64.__mro__
(<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.floating'>, <class 'numpy.inexact'>, <class 'numpy.number'>, <class 'numpy.generic'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> np.single, np.double, np.longfloat
(<class 'numpy.float32'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.longdouble'>)



From there, you could use:
any_np_float: NDArray[np.floating]
# or
any_np_float: NDArray[np.floating[Any]]  # CPython doesn't complain

I've also seen this pattern (although np.float32 (np.float16, ...) is not a Python built-in float descendant, as @user2357112 noticed):
any_np_float: NDArray[float]


I have tried NDArray[np.floating] but mypy still complains: sandbox.py:5: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "floating"  [type-arg] because np.floating itself is a generic. So it lost me there.

"But given the fact that all NumPy floats are (Python) built-in float descendants" - no they're not. Look at np.float32.__mro__ again.
